# EmberJS Custom Route Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n6Mp/) example, that I cannot apply a FixtureAdapater to. I am terrible at ember and am trying to learn but I cannot get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you so very much

HTML

```
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MessageManager">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

</script>

</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.MessageManager = Ember.Application.create();

MessageManager.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 13,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
});

MessageManager.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('MessageManager',{path :'/'});
});

MessageManager.MessageManagerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
var x = this.store.find('Message');
}
});

MessageManager.Message = DS.Model.extend({
id:DS.attr('id'),
SendingPhoneNumber : DS.attr('string'),
ReceivingPhoneNumber : DS.attr('string'),
DateReceived : DS.attr('date')});

MessageManager.Message.FIXTURES = [
{
id:1, 
SendingPhoneNumber :'555 555 9219',
ReceivingPhoneNumber :'555 555 1646',
Message : 'Why Do i have a 5 dollar charge on my phone bill',
DateReceived :'2014-02-21'
},
{
id:2,
 SendingPhoneNumber :'555 555 9219',
ReceivingPhoneNumber :'555 555 1678',
DateReceived :'2014-02-18'
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of errors a fixed version in on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pinoq/1/edit). I'm not sure which version of ember-data you're using, but ember-data changed the way you set the adapter, you set a factory instead of an instance:

`adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter`

Instead of:

`adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()`

Also, there's no need to set the id attribute on your model definition and you have an extra closing tag for the script element.

Hope this helps.